# Cannot open dialpad from android Webview as it shows tel: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

Spent hours to check why my code shows error "the webpage at tel: could not be loaded" to open-up dial-pad from my webview app.

I found many solutions and when implemented one to my code below it shows the same error as before

```
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.AlteredCharSequence;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private WebView webView;


        ProgressBar progressBar;
        Context context;
        String URL = "https://tajhalalmeats.com/";
        private Object MainActivity;
        private AlteredCharSequence Snackbar;
        private boolean doubleTap;
        private Object String;


        @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);


            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
            WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);



            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    if (url != null && ((url.startsWith("tel:")) || (url.startsWith("mailto:")) || (url.startsWith("https://api.whatsapp")) || (url.startsWith("http://api.whatsapp")))) {
                        view.getContext().startActivity (
                                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });



            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN|WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);



            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
            webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());


            //loading progressbar
            webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
                {
                    progressBar.setProgress(progress);

                    if (progress == 100) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    } else {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                }
            });

            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
                {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }
            });

            webView.loadUrl(URL);
        }



        //enabling back button to go to previous page


        @Override
        public void onBackPressed()
        {
            if (webView.canGoBack())
            {
                webView.goBack();
            }
            else if (doubleTap)
            {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Press again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
                doubleTap = true;
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        doubleTap = false;
                    }
                }, 2000);
            }
        }

}
```

I also used the below permissions in the AndroidManiFest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

Can anyone help where I am doing a mistake.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: @ admin this thread no more required as I found a solution in other post. please close this thread